# AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, argparse, python-3.8

I want to catch arguments, which are not defined. How to catch them?

First, I am going to define the parser:

```py
import argparse

parser.add_argument("--first", default='first', help='first argument')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then, I take a non-existing argument on purpose:

```py
args.x
```

The error shows up: `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'x'`

Well, I don't know how to handle it, just to say, that it does not exist, so I would set a variable to `False` for example.

Comment: In what context do you *need* to handle it, rather than just treat it as a bug and ensure that `x` *does* exist? That said, `getattr(args, 'x', False)`.

Comment: You can use `hasattr` to check for a value

Comment: ok. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `try`/`except` block

```
try:
    x = args.x
except AttributeError:
    x = False
```

That way if `x` is available from `args` you can assign that, otherwise fall back to a default value.